# How to remove the surrounding rectangle around the current line in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

This is the image showing the rectangle around the current line

[image: This is the image showing the rectangle around the current line]

I can't figure out how to remove this persisting rectangle around the current line
I am typing in. This is a feature of Visual Studio 2017 ( the one I am using now), of course - but I don't like it. Is there any way really remove this? Or am I out of luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > Display group > [ ] Highlight current line (uncheck)

Answer (score 2):

For MacOS:

1. Go to preferences->setting
2. search setting -> type "Render line highlight "
3. Choose none or gutter (which current line indicator is on the left side line number)

Answer (score 0):

Search for `Occurrences Highlight` in Settings and set `Render Line Highlight` to `none`.